# f5 - refresh only the frame

Tags: html, frame

Is it possible to refresh only one frame in the windows and not all the frames?
My problem is that i have a page index.php and inside there are two frames - menu and content. when the user clicks on refresh(f5) the index.php has been loaded again and the content page is blank.

What can i do?

Comment: You mean you're using a frameset?

Comment: This behavior is purely browser-dependent and you have no control over it. Browsers will always reload the topmost page when pressing the reload button/key.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with javascript's usage in page refresh. You can try that instead of traditional html do a job.

```
javascript:location.reload(false)
```

will do a page reload from the cache. Set this to your content page and for menu page you can set this.

```
javascript:location.reload(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store the last page selected by the user in cookie (using client side code) then in the page load even (client side again) check for that cookie and if exists, load that page by default instead of showing blank page.

Using jQuery accessing cookies becomes really simple: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie